# adding a sub query to a case statement in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I hope you can help. I have the below query, which has a case statement.

I want to say:

IF the domain is in the other table, then return the domain name, else, mark it as 'other'

I am using Hive & get the error:

```
Unsupported SubQuery Expression 'cleandomain': Currently SubQuery expressions are only allowed as Where Clause predicates
```

Is there some other way I can achieve the same?

```
SELECT *,
       CASE
         WHEN cleandomain IN (SELECT cleandomain
                              FROM   keenek1.daily_top_doms) THEN cleandomain
         ELSE 'other'
       END AS status
FROM   (SELECT hour,.....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is using [in_file(string str, string filename)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) function.

Put the list of domains in the text file, one domain per line, txt file and call `in_file` function in the CASE statement:

```
  CASE
     WHEN in_file(cleandomain,'file/path/daily_top_doms.txt') THEN cleandomain
     ELSE 'other'
   END AS status
```

Another solution is to aggregate the list of domains into array in the subquery, join using cross join and use array_contains(). This may work much faster if the list is not too big:

```
with dom as (
SELECT collect_set(cleandomain) dom
  FROM   keenek1.daily_top_doms
)

select 
case when array_contains(d.dom, s.cleardomain) then s.cleandomain
         else 'other'
 end as status
from (your query) s cross join dom d --one row cross join
```